# Derive equation for half-wave rectifier with inductor and DC source load

Tags: circuit-analysis, rectifier

I am trying to analyze a half-wave rectifier with an inductor and DC source load. I am reading a book on power electronics and the equations the author came up with are shown along with the circuit. I understand the circuit but I do not get the math.

I understand how he got from the first equation to the second equation  but I do not understand his algebra to get from the second equation to the third. Shouldn't it be ω/L instead of 1/ωL? I tried the circuit in LTspice and it seems to match the third equation closely, so I believe his final equation is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the first two equations are correct, then the third one is not. Unless he's using some obscure trick. But it looks like simple algebra.

-Subtract Vdc from both sides.
-Multiply both sides by w/L.

I think you are correct in assuming it is w/L, and not 1/wL.

Comment: (`\$\omega\$` reads \$\omega\$.)

Comment: @greybeard I solved the equation in straight time domain then replaced t with \$\omega\$t. So his final equation 1/\$\omega\$t is correct. I believe there is a problem with his initial substitution.